# Transform Google Earth Engine script to Python with Landsat 8 temporal data

Tags: google-earth-engine, python-3, data-frame, google-earth-engine-python-api

I am doing a study for my work and I need to adapt my Google Earth Engine script in Python, but I am encountering some problems.

Here is a Google Earth Engine script:

```
 //Importing image and geometry:
var l8 = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR")
//    geometry = /* color: #d63000 */ee.Geometry.Polygon(
//        [[[-80.92489760146748, 25.433457120928352],
//          [-80.64474623427998, 25.488013471687964],
//          [-80.57882826552998, 25.710940372707608],
//          [-81.02377455459248, 25.770317250349557],
//          [-80.95236342177998, 25.552457242621447]]]);

//Filtering date, polygon, and cloudiness
    var image = l8.filterDate ('2010-09-01', '2021-12-31')
                .filterBounds (geometry)
                .filterMetadata ('CLOUD_COVER', 'less_than', 1);

    //NDVI calculation:
    var ndvi_func = function (i) {
      var ndvi = i.normalizedDifference (['B5', 'B4']).rename ('NDVI')
      return i.addBands(ndvi);
    }

    var image_ndvi = image.map(ndvi_func);

    //Calculating year wise NDVI
    var year = ee.List.sequence(2010,2021);
    var year_func = function(y){
      var range = ee.Filter.calendarRange (y, y, 'year');
      return image_ndvi.select('NDVI').filter(range).mean().set ('Year', y)
    };
    var yearwise_ndvi = ee.ImageCollection(year.map(year_func));
    print (yearwise_ndvi);
    Map.addLayer (yearwise_ndvi)

//Creating time-series chart:
var chart = ui.Chart.image.series ({
  imageCollection: image_ndvi.select('NDVI'),
  region: geometry,
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
  scale: 30})

print(chart);
```

Figure:
[image: NDVI]

The script above presents an NDVI time series for a region and I need to do it in Python. Here is a script that shows the errors in Python:

```
l8 = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR")
geometry = ee.Geometry.Polygon([[[-80.92489760146748, 25.433457120928352],
                                 [-80.64474623427998, 25.488013471687964],
                                 [-80.57882826552998, 25.710940372707608],
                                 [-81.02377455459248, 25.770317250349557],
                                 [-80.95236342177998, 25.552457242621447]]]);

#Filtering date, polygon, and cloudiness
image = l8.filterDate ('2010-09-01', '2021-12-31')
image  = image.filterBounds (geometry)
image  = image.filterMetadata ('CLOUD_COVER', 'less_than', 1);

#NDVI calculation:
def ndvi_func(i):
    ndvi = i.normalizedDifference (['B5', 'B4']).rename ('NDVI')
    return i.addBands(ndvi)

image_ndvi = ndvi_func(image.map)

#Calculating year wise NDVI
year = ee.List.sequence(2010,2021);
def year_func(y):
    range = ee.Filter.calendarRange (y, y, 'year');
    return image_ndvi.select('NDVI').filter(range).mean().set ('Year', y)

yearwise_ndvi = ee.ImageCollection(year.map(year_func));
    print (yearwise_ndvi);
    Map.addLayer (yearwise_ndvi)

#Creating time-series chart:
chart = ui.Chart.image.series ({imageCollection: image_ndvi.select('NDVI'),
                                region: geometry,
                                reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
                                scale: 30})

print(chart)
```

The problem is that the functions do not load the data.

How can I load NDVI data by date into a DataFrame?

I would also like to have daily NDVI instead of monthly / yearly, but I'm not getting it on Google Earth Engine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running the given Javascript doesn't produce the chart that is displayed, but to gather annual statistics for a region, you need to replicate the data aggregation that's being done by ui.Chart.image.series (since none of the ui functions exist in Python).

Additionally, Your use of map() is incorrect and backwards.  It should be:

```
image_ndvi = image.map(ndvi_func)
```

Here's the full python to get a Dataframe from the yearly spatial and temporal means.  You have to relax the cloud cover filtering to get enough data to have a value in each year, but you should probably be doing cloud masking instead of filtering anyway (See: https://code.earthengine.google.com/?scriptPath=Examples%3ACloud%20Masking%2FLandsat8%20Surface%20Reflectance)

```
import ee
import pandas as pd

ee.Initialize()

l8 = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR")
geometry = ee.Geometry.Polygon([[[-80.92489760146748, 25.433457120928352],
                                 [-80.64474623427998, 25.488013471687964],
                                 [-80.57882826552998, 25.710940372707608],
                                 [-81.02377455459248, 25.770317250349557],
                                 [-80.95236342177998, 25.552457242621447]]])

#Filtering date, polygon, and cloudiness
images = (l8.filterDate('2010-09-01', '2021-12-31')
          .filterBounds(geometry)
          .filter('CLOUD_COVER < 5'))

#NDVI calculation:
def ndvi_func(i):
    ndvi = i.normalizedDifference (['B5', 'B4']).rename('NDVI')
    return i.addBands(ndvi)

images_ndvi = images.map(ndvi_func)

#Calculating year wise NDVI.  Result is a list of dictionaries.
years = ee.List.sequence(2010,2021)
def year_func(y):
    range = ee.Filter.calendarRange (y, y, 'year')
    mean = (images_ndvi
            .filter(range)
            .select('NDVI')
            .mean()
            .reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.mean(), geometry, 30))
    return mean.set('year', y)

yearwise_ndvi = years.map(year_func).getInfo()
df = pd.DataFrame(yearwise_ndvi)
print(df)
```

Comment: Thank you so much!
Would you help me how can I have the daily NDVI?
How can I get the average polygon of the NDVI at the time of passing the L8?
Thank you again.

Comment: @LucasFagundes MODIS MOD09GA product should be good for daily NDVI and full coverage rather than Landsat

Comment: @ManmeetSingh Thank you very much! I will look for how to implement MODIS.
However, what if I wanted the NDVI data at the time of the Landsat8 pass and not by year average?

Comment: @LucasFagundes for that you will have to loop over the date arguments in filterDate. For example, you want the NDVI for the date 2010-09-01 then your call should be like l8.filterDate('2010-09-01', '2010-09-02') The end date is exclusive in Google Earth Engine . So you will get the NDVI for that date. I think we can safely assume that NDVI wont change within the day, so that's how you can get the NDVI by the Landsat pass

Comment: @ManmeetSingh I understood and thanks for the explanation, but above the figure and using the script that I put as an example the NDVI figure from the Landsat passage. Wouldn't it be possible to make the figure the same with a DF only with the average NDVI of the geometry at the moment of passing?

Comment: @LucasFagundes I don't think it can be possibly known beforehand whether the satellite passed over the geometry/region. So you would have to loop over all the times to aggregate the data and when a satellite pass is not there the values would be nan. Once you collect this in an array you can just remove the nan values to get only the NDVI for the the time there is a satellite pass over the region

Comment: @ManmeetSingh, Thank you very much! I am going to try.